# Dispatch ngrx actions from Browser console

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm developing an application with Angular2/ngrx. For debugging purposes, I'd like to dispatch ngrx actions from the browser console where. Is there a way to access the store and other parts of the application from the browser js console?

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: yes, I'm using angular-cli which in turn uses webpack

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to manually add store to global window object `window.store = this.store` from where it's available, e.g. AppComponent.

You'll be able to do `window.store.dispatch(...)` or `window.store.subscribe(state => doSomethingWithState)` in console.

This might seem hacky but its most simple approach with no dependencies on plugins, libs, etc. which might be good enough for dev environment.

Comment: What you propose works.. kinda. After dispatching an action from command line, the action is not executed until I trigger another dispatch using the normal web by interacting with the webapp. Then, however, the manually dispatched action is executed. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

Using the redux devtools chrome plugin you can dispatch actions.
On the bottom next to "Lock" there is a button that shows the input shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it out. Nonetheless, I'm wondering how to do this in the console. How does the devtools plugin achieve this?